# Classify type of tweet (tweet/retweet/mention) based on tweet text in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

Pulling from a couple of different examples, I've been able to create a simple Python script that parses the JSON output from the Twitter Streaming API, and prints out the `screen_name` and `text` for each tweet.  I would like to modify my code to also classify each tweet as one of the following:

(1) **Retweet** --> There is an "RT @anyusername" somewhere in the tweet text column

(2) **Mention** --> There is an "@anyusername" but no "RT @anyusername" in the tweet column

(3) **Tweet** --> There is no "RT @anyusername" nor any "@anyusername" in the tweet column

I can do this in Excel with the following formula, but I can figure it out in Python yet.

`=IF(IFERROR(FIND("RT @",B2)>0,"False"),"Retweet",IF(IFERROR(FIND("@",B2)>0,"False"),"Mention","Tweet"))`

***Existing Code***

```
import json
import sys
from csv import writer

with open(sys.argv[1]) as in_file, \
    open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as out_file:
    print >> out_file, 'tweet_author, tweet_text, tweet_type'
    csv = writer(out_file)

    for line in in_file:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
        except:
            pass

        tweet_text = tweet['text']

        row = (
        tweet['user']['screen_name'],
        tweet_text
        )
        values = [(value.encode('utf8') if hasattr(value, 'encode') else value) for value in row]
        csv.writerow(values)
```

Comment: I think the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) might be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any python interpreter here, but it should be something similar to this:

```
import re


def url_match(tweet):
    match = re.match(r'RT\s@....+', tweet)
    if match:
        return "RT"
    else:
        match = re.match(r'@....+', tweet)
        if match:
           return "mention"
        else
           return "tweet"
```

**Note:** this will work for this classification, but if **you want to retrieve usernames** i.e. @USERNAME you will have to tweak this a little more.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Kyllopardiun.  This function works well to each individual tweet, just as I would like.  However, I've been trying to integrate it into my existing code, so then the type of tweet is output in column 3, but I haven't been successful yet.  Any help is again appreciated.