# Classify type of tweet based on regex in python

Tags: python, regex, twitter

Extension of this question: [Classify type of tweet (tweet/retweet/mention) based on tweet text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526410/classify-type-of-tweet-tweet-retweet-mention-based-on-tweet-text-in-python)

I would like to classify each tweet in my dataset as one of the following, and append the tweet type to each record in the dataset. Currently, when I run my script shown below, I get the `[None]` returned, so obviously I'm missing something here.

**Current Format:**

```
 ['CREATED_AT']['text']
```

**Desired Format:**

```
['CREATED_AT']['text']['tweet_type']
```

**Tweet Classifications:**

(1) Retweet --> There is an "RT @anyusername" somewhere in the tweet text column

(2) Mention --> There is an "@anyusername" but no "RT @anyusername" in the tweet column

(3) Tweet --> There is no "RT @anyusername" nor any "@anyusername" in the tweet column

**Code:**

```
import json
import time
import re

# load Twitter Streaming JSON data into a dict
def import_tweets(parameter1):
    data = []
    for line in open(parameter1):
      try: 
        data.append(json.loads(line))
      except:
        pass

    for i in data:
        i['CREATED_AT'] = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.strptime(i['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))
    return data

# Extract timestamp and tweet text into a list
def extract_tweets(parameter2):
    tweets = []
    for i in parameter2:
        tweets.append(
        [i['CREATED_AT'],
         i['text']]        
        )
    return tweets

# Classify each tweet as retweet/mention/tweet
def tweet_type(parameter3):
    tweet_type = []
    for i in parameter3:
        match = re.match(r'RT\s@....+', i[1])   
        if match:
            tweet_type.append([i, 'retweet'])
        else:
            match = re.match(r'@....+', i[1])
            if match:
               tweet_type.append([i, 'reply'])
            else:
                match = re.match(r'....+@', i[1])
                if match:
                   tweet_type.append([i, 'mention'])
                else:
                   tweet_type.append([i, 'tweet'])                
    return tweet_type    

data = import_tweets('tweets.json')
tweets = extract_tweets(data)
tweet_type = tweet_type(tweets)

# Print sample to make sure tweet text was classified properly
print tweet_type[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. `tweet_type.append(i.append(['tweet']))` -- calls to `list.append()` don't return anything (meaning they implicitly return None). You are appending None to tweet_type. This is the main problem.
2. `return tweet_type` is indented too much to the right -- the loop exits the function on the first iteration.

Comment: @Curtis You need to replace `i.append(...)` with the value you want to place to tweet_type. Because you don't have docstrings and every parameter is `parameter1` it's hard to tell what you intended to happen in there. :)

Comment: my ultimate goal is to take a list of tweets (`['CREATED_AT']['text']`, and based on the type of tweet, I want to append the type of tweet to each line so I ultimately end up with `['CREATED_AT']['text']['tweet_type']`

Comment: Maybe you could edit code in your original post to make it more readable?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import time
import re

def import_tweets(parameter1):
    """
    Loads data from Twitter Streaming API for analysis.

    Args:
        parameter1:  input file
    Returns:
        List of nested dictionaries
    """

    # load JSON data into a dict    
    data = []
    for line in open(parameter1):
        try: 
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        except:
            pass

    # Transform Twitter tweet date/time format into standard date/time format
    for i in data:
        i['CREATED_AT'] = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.strptime(i['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))

    # Classify each tweet as a retweet/reply/mention/tweet
    for i in data:
        match = re.match(r'RT\s@....+', i['text'])   
        if match:
            i['TYPE'] = 'retweet'
        else:
            match = re.match(r'@....+', i['text'])
            if match:
                i['TYPE'] = 'reply'
            else:
                match = re.match(r'....+@', i['text'])
                if match:
                    i['TYPE'] = 'mention'
                else:
                    i['TYPE'] = 'tweet'

    return data
```